# SpeechRecognitionEngine RecognizeCompleted event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, event-handling, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have been searching for this problem for a while but I didn't find anything helpful.
I want perform a continuous speech recognition `using System.Speech.Recognition;` from a wav file however , I want to return the result when the recognition engine finish its work.
I found a [solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtodefaultaudiodevice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  to use `RecognizeCompleted` event handler but it doesn't fire at all.
Recognition code:

```
        SpeechRecognitionEngine speechRecognitionEngine = null;
        bool completed = false;
        // create the engine
        speechRecognitionEngine = createSpeechEngine("en-GB");

        // hook to events
        speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(engine_SpeechRecognized);
        speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeCompleted += new EventHandler<RecognizeCompletedEventArgs>(recognizer_RecognizeCompleted);

        // load dictionary
        speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile("C:\\Converted Audio\\BBC1 cut sport.wav");

        // start listening for continuous speech recognition 
        speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        while (!completed)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(333);
        }
```

Event handler code:

```
void recognizer_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        completed = true;
    }
```

Comment: Couple of possibilities:  1) Recognition isn't completing; check the `SpeechRecognitionRejected` event.  2) At a bare minimum, set up a handler for `SpeechDetected` and `SpeechHypothesized` events to make sure that data is reaching the recognizer.

Comment: Also make sure your grammars are enabled.